# Get RGB value from a pixel

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on a problem in which I am plotting a GeoTIFF image using matplotlib. I want to implement a function such that when I click on the image, the function must return the RGB value of the pixel on which I clicked, using matplotlib only.

I had seen all the previous solutions provided on Stack Overflow, none of those worked for me.

Here is my code:

```
src = rasterio.open("rgb.tif")
src1 = rasterio.plot.reshape_as_image(src.read())
#segments = quickshift(image, ratio=1, kernel_size=20, max_dist=80,
           #return_tree=False, sigma=0, convert2lab=True, random_seed=42


def onclick(event):
    print(event)
    global ix, iy
    global area
    area = 7
    ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata


    print ('ix ',ix)
    print ("iy ",iy)

    #X =  '${}$'.format(ix)
    #Y =  '${}$'.format(iy)
    datacursor(bbox=dict(fc='white'),formatter="longitude:{x:.2f}\nlatitude:{y:.2f}\ncolor:{z}".format)

    return
    #print ("color ",image[int(event.xdata)][int(event.ydata)])

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
graph1 = show(src.read(), transform=src.transform , ax  = ax)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It would make sense if you link to the previous solutions and tell in how far they didn't work for you. Else, one could just close this as duplicate of any of them, which would not bring you closer to a solution.

Comment: Or provide the code attempts you have now, and then describe why they are not working. Someone might be able to help you get your code working.

Comment: thanks for the reply, Actually I am stuck at a point while reading matplotlib docs, They are using format_coord attribute but I think we cant use it here to get RGB value. Also can u please guide me how to use contours here to find RGB value for a pixel. I am providing my code snippet above...please help

Comment: Do you want to print the RGB values, or show them in the GUI taskbar, or use them for something in your code? Note that you would want to use `numpy.round` instead of `int` because pixels are centered.

Comment: #ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I want to store them in a global variable for further use in code. I have a CSV file consisting of 3 attributes; lat, long, and RGB values and the image is plotted such that Lat on X-axis and Long on Y-axis but I am unable to get RGB for particular lat and long value from CSV because they are slightly changing each time I plot them on a figure in matplotlib

Answer (score 2):

Suppose 
`im = plt.imshow(data)`
is an image you plot. Then, if `data` is a numpy array from a three channel tif image, the RGB values of coordinates `i,j` is `data[j,i,:]`. If `data` is a single channel image, it would be plotted with a colormap. In that case, the RGB value is `im.cmap(im.norm(data[j,i]))`.

Comment: Actually, my coordinates are latitude and longitude and I don't want to change them to another reference system like rows and columns but numpy array that I am using stores data in form of rows and column , that's the point where problem lies

Comment: I don't know what `src.transform` is; but you will want to use it to get the correct coordinates then.

Comment: thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I will surely look into that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the RGB-value of a pixel you could use the following:

```
def onclick(event):
   r, g, b = event.inaxes.get_images()[0].get_cursor_data(event)[:3]
   print([r, g, b])
```

This way you don't need to use complicated indexing and you can also zoom-in and find the RGB-values